# confirming program flow

Tags: java, multithreading, program-flow

can someone tell if the code below would work fine?

```
class CriticalSection{

int iProcessId, iCounter=0;

public static boolean[] freq = new boolean[Global.iParameter[2]];

int busy;

//constructors

CriticalSection(){}

CriticalSection(int iPid){
    this.iProcessId = iPid;
}

int freqAvailable(){

for(int i=0; i<
Global.iParameter[2]; i++){

        if(freq[i]==true){
            //this means that there is no frequency available and the request will be dropped
            iCounter++;
        }   
    }
    if(iCounter == freq.length)
        return 3;

    BaseStaInstance.iNumReq++;
    return enterCritical();
}

int enterCritical(){

    int busy=0;
    for(int i=0; i<Global.iParameter[2]; i++){
        if(freq[i]==true){
            freq[i] = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    //implement a thread that will execute the critical section simultaneously as the (contd down)
    //basestation leaves it critical section and then generates another request
    UseFrequency freqInUse = new UseFrequency;
    busy = freqInUse.start(i);

//returns control back to the main program

    return 1;   
}
}

class UseFrequency extends Thread {

    int iFrequency=0;

     UseFrequency(int i){
        this.iFrequency = i;
     }
     //this class just allows the frequency to be used in parallel as the other basestations carry on making requests
    public void run() {
        try {
            sleep(((int) (Math.random() * (Global.iParameter[5] - Global.iParameter[4] + 1) ) + Global.iParameter[4])*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    }

    CriticalSection.freq[iFrequency] = true;

    stop();

}
```

Comment: Maybe if you reformat/reindent the code properly. The indentation is bogus and this makes code hard to interpret. If you're using Eclipse, just press `Ctrl+Shift+F`. Further also tell in detail what the actual problem is with the code. What happens? What happens not? How doesn't it suffice? An SSCCE (http://sscce.org) which we can just copy'n'paste'n'run would be great.

Comment: Instead of posting a huge block of code, you might consider posting a more specific question about the code with relevant snippets.  Or at least format it properly; it's really hard to read without indents.

Comment: How can I tell you if it will work, if you don't tell me what it's intended to do?

Comment: -1 for now because the OP hasn't responded to the comments in the ~20 minutes since they were posted.

Comment: Hey, i'm really sorry, I just come back every 45 minutes or so to check for answers.
Jemiah below has answered my question.
I just wanted to know if I was implementing the threads right. I'm sorry for assuming many things and not phrasing my question right. I'll make sure to be more clear next time.

Comment: @user282544: I'm curious what environment you're in, where you can't even try to compile your code.  At first I assumed you had copied bits and pieces at a time out of order.  If we understood your situation better, we might be able to provide better guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this code will not even compile. For example, your "UseFrequency" class has a constructor and a run() method, but then you have two lines `CriticalSection.freq[iFrequency] = true;` and 
`stop();` that aren't in any method body - they are just sitting there on their own.

If you get the code to compile it still will not work like you expect because you have multiple threads and no concurrency control. That means the different threads can "step on eachother" and corrupt shared data, like your "freq" array. Any time you have multiple threads you need to protect access to shared variables with a synchronized block. The Java Tutorial on concurrency explains this here http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Comment: CriticalSection.freq[iFrequency] = true just sets the boolean array from the CriticalSection class back to true.
and Ive used stop() to kill the current thread.

But yes, I understand what you've mentioned about the synchronized block. Would the code below ensure concurrency? Ive omitted most of the code, synchronized block concerns me.


int enterCritical(){

 int busy=0;
 for(int i=0; i<Global.iParameter[2]; i++){
  synchronized(Global.freqLock){
   if(freq[i]==true){
    freq[i] = false;
    break;
   }
  }
 }

 synchronized(Global.freqLock){
  CriticalSection.freq[iFrequency] = true;
 }

Comment: @user282544: Comments don't have formatting, you should really edit your original post when you have changes like this.  I will point out, however, that stop() is deprecated, and with good reason: http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Thanks also for bringing to my notice the idea of editing my original post with code changes, it did not occur to me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried compiling and testing it?  Are you using an IDE like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)?  You can step through your program in the debugger to see what its doing. The way your question is structured no one can tell either way if your program is doing the right or wrong thing, because nothing is specified in the comments of the code, nor in the question posed.